# Insert data into multiple databases and tables at one go

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to use prepared statement to insert into several databases and tables. Is it possible to insert into multiple databases and tables?
Here is the code that i have tried, can you tell me what should be done next because i am stuck in this part. The data is being captures from textboxes.

```
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost   /mirroreddatabase","root","");
Connection con1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/breastcancerdatabase","root","");
Connection con2 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/genedetailsdatabase","root","");
 String sql= "Insert into omimmirrored(id,genesymbol,sequencelinks)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

 String sql2 = "Insert into breastcancer_genename(id,symbol,geneName)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst1=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql2);

 String sql3 = "Insert into genedetails(id,symbol,GeneDetailsLinks)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst2=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql3);

 String sql4 = "Insert into breastcancer_synonym(id,symbol,geneName)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst3=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql4);
```

Comment: You're not using `con1` or `con2`. Also, you might prefer to use batching.

Comment: how will i save the data if i am using this method of prepared statment. con1 and con2 are connections for the different databases

Comment: Not sure what's you intention of doing all at one, but I notice you have con, con1, con2, your prepare statements all using con only, it is a mistake right?  I like to keep things simple, I would have 4 different methods each would insert data into it own database.  You can wrap a transaction around it if need to ensure that all or nothing.  But remember, each connection, statement should complete with a .close() method and preferably be in the finally block of a try catch.

Comment: I am trying to insert data into multiple databases.Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one connection and grant to the user of this connection privileges on all databases so you can do insert in all them.

For grant privileges to root on all databases you can do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You just need to put the database as prefix (i.e. instead of `insert into breastcancer_genename` you mus put `insert into breastcancerdatabase.breastcancer_genename`).

```
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost   /mirroreddatabase","root","");

 String sql= "Insert into omimmirrored(id,genesymbol,sequencelinks)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

 String sql2 = "Insert into breastcancerdatabase.breastcancer_genename(id,symbol,geneName)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst1=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql2);

 String sql3 = "Insert into genedetailsdatabase.genedetails(id,symbol,GeneDetailsLinks)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst2=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql3);

 String sql4 = "Insert into breastcancerdatabase.breastcancer_synonym(id,symbol,geneName)values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement pst3=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql4);
```

About the GRANT sentence (from MySQL documentation):

> The GRANT statement grants privileges to MySQL user accounts. GRANT
>   also serves to specify other account characteristics such as use of
>   secure connections and limits on access to server resources. To use
>   GRANT, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege, and you must have the
>   privileges that you are granting.

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: sorry but i am new to grant. can you explain me using my codes? I am using NetBeans

Comment: GRANT is a sentence that you must use on MySQL, not in Java

Comment: ok i understood that. but how will the connections be established?

Comment: i am unable to save my records